# MatrixExp introduces nonconstant expression #1 independent of variables

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I am trying to use Mathematica to minimize a particular cost function. One part of the definition of the cost function is taking the matrix exponential of an arbitrary $4 \times 4$ Hermitian matrix. In taking this matrix exponential, Mathematica seems to introduce a `#1`, which is a "nonconstant expression independent of the variables" where the variables are the arbitrary entries of the Hermitian matrix. As a result, I cannot use `FindInstance` to solve my minimization problem. The code is

```
h = {{h11, h12, h13, h14}, {Conjugate[h12], h22, h23, 
     h24}, {Conjugate[h13], Conjugate[h23], h33, 
     h34}, {Conjugate[h14], Conjugate[h24], Conjugate[h34], h44}};
MatrixExp[h]
```

From this, you can see that the result of `MatrixExp[h]` has the `#1`s in question. Any help with how to deal with this situation would be appreciated!

Comment: add // Normal at the end?

Comment: @chris I just tried this and it did not work.

Comment: Try `MatrixExp[h]//Normal//ToRadicals` ? The expression will be very very large. So you might be better off giving values to hijs?

Comment: MatrixExp needs the eigenvalues, the zeros of the characteristic polynomial. Zeros of the general 4th order polynomial are impossible to handle: Even if the roots are expressible by  algebraic expressions in roots of order 2 and 3 in the complex coefficients, its impossible to identify them by an arbitrary enumeration, invariant under permutations. No problem with numerical coefficients.

Comment: @RolandF I see...so minimizing the cost function I have in mind will be impossible, then? Since I am solving for these matrix coefficients.